# Cannot move ckeditor 4 selection to beginning

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I've been exploring numerous solutions in stackoverflow and elsewhere to try to get ckeditor 4 to scroll to the top after I've programmatically added a number of pages to it, using CKEditor's InsertHtml function. After adding my html, which looks fine, I want to position the cursor at the beginning.

Here's one of a variety of things I've tried without success:

```
function MoveCaretToStart(myEditor) {
    var range = new CKEDITOR.dom.range( editor.document );
    range.selectNodeContents(editor.document.getBody());
    range.moveToElementEditStart(range.root);  // also tried range.collapse(true);
    range.select();
}
...
MoveCaretToStart(CKEDITOR.instances['myEditor']);  // which already has contents in it
```

This doesn't throw any errors, but also doesn't move the cursor position (it remains at the end of the doc). I thought this one would be easy, but it sure hasn't been. Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE on 11/1:**
I just did the following test: created a simple html page with just a text area, removed all extra plugins. I display the page, enter text in the editor (which works fine), and then use the JS console to call MoveEditorToBeginning(); Nothing happens, and the console echoes "undefined". I am stymied. Here's the entire html page source (using CkEditor 4.22):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<textarea cols="80" id="docBody" name="docBody" tabindex="1" accesskey="d" rows="10">    </textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
CKEDITOR.replace( 'docBody',
{
    removePlugins:  'elementspath,stylesheetparser,a11yhelp ,autosave,docprops,fakeobjects,find,image,link,magicline,pagebreak,pastefromword,scayt,specialchar,texttransform,wordcount,wsc',

});
//]]>

function MoveEditorCaretToBeginning() {
var theEditor = CKEDITOR.instances['docBody'];
    var body        = theEditor.document.getBody();
    var range       = new CKEDITOR.dom.range(body);
    range.selectNodeContents(body);
    range.collapse(true);
    var selection   = theEditor.getSelection();
    selection.selectRanges([range]);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what works for me (`editor` would be `myEditor` in your case):

```
var body = editor.document.getBody();
var range = new CKEDITOR.dom.range(body);
range.selectNodeContents(body);
range.collapse(true);
var selection = editor.getSelection();
selection.selectRanges([range]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work for me in either Chrome or Firefox. If i use ckeditor after creating my doc and then use the Javascript console in either browser to invoke my "MoveEditorCaretToStart" function, nothing happens in ckeditor, and the console displays an "undefined" message, which is coming from ckeditor code. So I'm confused. I should mention that I have two different ckeditor instances on my page, but I can't see how that would be interfering.

Comment: @GaryHillerson, what's your version of CKEditor? Mine is 4.2, and that code worked cross-browser last time I checked it.

Comment: I'm using 4.22, freshly downloaded last week. I just did a simple test, where I use only one CKEditor instance and use the standard config.js (instead of my customized version). I eliminated all HTML except for the CKEDITOR textarea, and eliminated all Javascript except for ckeditor. My code puts up an empty editor, which works fine. I insert a big chunk of html--either by hand or programmatically-- and then call that "move to beginning" function. It doesn't work. Uggh. Thanks for your help, though.